# Searching in a directory for specific file that contains a folder path and copy it in python

Tags: python, string, path, copy

i am really new to python and i learn a lot everyday.
i want to do an automatic script that will help me in my work.

I have a specific folder that contains some files, i don't want my tool to be file specific because i want to reuse this script so i want it to look in the files for a specific title,

lets say that the file has somewhere in the middle the line "paths" and under it many paths like "file path="Some path"

I want my script to go to the directory i specifiy and look for a file containing this title "path"
copy one of the paths (they will be right under it) and thats it.

then im going to use this path to download files and more but this part i already done.
I just don't know how to look for specific string in files when a specific folder is given and copy the string i want.

So lets say i have a folder (C:\Folder)
and in the folder i have 3 files (1,2,3)

i want to look for a file containing this kind of pattern "paths"
and copy the paths or at least one of them that specified under it.
they will be like "file path=C:\somepath"
So the file content is like

blabla

blabla

paths

file path=C:\somepath

file path=C:\somepath2

blabla

i want to copy the C:\somepath and use it as part of my job.

Thanks a lot for all the helpers its more than important to me.

Comment: Well, if you expect help, you should start by explaining your problem in proper English.
Right now, it's impossible to follow what you're trying to say, with your screwed up punctuation and grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is looking at all files within a directory. That's [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir).

Next, you need to open each file in a loop. So, so far, we've got:

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(filename) as f:
```

Now, what do we do with each file? There are a few different options—we could read in the whole file (or `mmap` it) and then use `str.find` or regex methods to parse it, or we could just go line by line and keep track of our state, or we could transform the sequence of lines with `itertools` functions, or we could build a state machine and run it, or…

I think the simplest for a novice is to go line by line manually. But let's wrap it up in a function. So:

```
def parse_file(f):
    paths = []
    found_paths = False
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if not found_paths:
            if line == 'paths':
                found_paths = True
        else:
            if line.startswith('file path='):
                paths.append(line[len('file path='):])
            else:
                break
    return paths

paths = []
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(filename) as f:            
        paths.append(parse_file(f))
```

---

> how can i stop after finding the first line?

Just `break` after reading the first line. So, instead of this:

```
if line.startswith('file path='):
    paths.append(line[len('file path='):])
else:
    break
```

Do this:

```
if line.startswith('file path='):
    paths.append(line[len('file path='):])
break
```

> how i can fix it to put the paths in different index in the dictionary because it puts all of them in the first field

Well, right now, you're *not* creating a dictionary, you're creating a list.

If you want a dictionary, mapping, say, each file to the list of file paths in that file, that's easy. Instead of this:

```
paths = []
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(filename) as f:
        paths.append(parse_file(f))
```

Do this:

```
paths = {}
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(filename) as f:            
        paths[filename] = parse_file(f)
```

However, it may be simpler to not build a list in the first place if you only want one value. You just need to return the pathname if you find one, and something that can't possibly be a pathname (like `None`) if you don't.

> how do i modify problematic path. because the paths in file are saved in this format -  and i want to copy only C:\folder\folder

Well, first, my code won't even find anything with that format. You asked to find lines like `file path=…`, so I used `startswith`, but `<file path=` doesn't start with that. So you first need to change the `startswith` that you check. Meanwhile, you also need to handle the quotes, and the angle brackets.

At this point, it looks like just dumb text processing may not be the right answer. This looks like XML. The easiest way to parse an XML document is to use an XML parser, like `xml.elementtree`. If it's not an XML document, just a line-based document that has XML nodes stuck in it, you *could* still try to parse each line as an XML document, but it might be easier to use `re` with a suitable regular expression (e.g., `r'<file path="(.*?)"/>'` will match just the part between quotes). Without knowing what your actual input text looks like, I can't give you anything more specific than this.

Finally, after you've done that step, it looks like you want to remove the trailing backslash off directory paths, so you get `C:\folder\folder` even though the file had `C:\folder\folder\`. You could use functions in `os.path` for this, but if you're sure that the paths will always be in Windows format, it may be simpler to just tell it to remove any trailing backslashes, with `rstrip('\\')`. (Note the double backslash there, because you need to escape backslashes in Python strings.)

Comment: Thank you very much, but i have few issues. how can i stop after finding the first line? or how i can fix it to put the paths in different index in the dictionary because it puts all of them in the first field (and in the end i want to use one) my second question is how do i modify problematic path. because the paths in file are saved in this format - <file path="C:\folder\folder\"/>  and i want to copy only C:\folder\folder. thanks!!!

Comment: Since you've got lots of questions, let me update the answer.

Comment: Ok no need for an answer to the first question i just do paths[0][0] but how do i manipulate the path, the result of the script now is "C:\folder\folder\"/> in the file it was <file path="C:\folder\folder\"/>   - the result i want is C:\folder\folder - thanks!

Comment: Well, I already answered both parts (and all the subparts of them). As I said, if you're trying to parse XML, you should have said that in the first place, and you probably shouldn't do it this way.

Comment: Yes its an xml file, im sorry i didnt say. im playing with the xml parser you said, having some issues. so my file has many text but in the middle i have <paths> and under i have <file path=C:\folder\folder\"/> and more paths in this format. right now the script copy the line into the list as "C:\folder\folder\"/> and i want the result as normal path in windows. you suggest to do manipulation on the string or use the xml parser? the xml parser is kinda hard because the path is a deep sub-tree child. and im already pretty close to the solution without the xml parser

Comment: I'd suggest using an XML parser, but… let me write up a new answer with the details.

Comment: my "locator" is - if line.startswith('<file path=') as i said it copies the line and show it like this - C:\folder\folder\"/> , i just need to get rid of the \"/> and make the backslash into /

Comment: "C:\folder\folder\"/> is what i have, i need C:/folder/folder

Comment: Please see the other answer. This is the right answer for what you originally asked, but it's wrong for what you actually want. Also, please read ["What is the XY problem?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). If you explain what you actually want to do, with all details exactly as they are, it won't take you hours of back and forth to get answers.

Answer (score -1):

From your comments, your data is actually XML, and what you want is the `path` attribute of every (or the first) `file` node in the first `paths` node.

This is actually a lot easier to write—and much more robust—in terms of an XML parser.

For example, these are probably all valid `file` nodes:

```
<file path="C:\Foo\Bar" />
<file path="C:\Baz\Qux"/>
    <file path="C:\Foo\Bar" />
<file path="C:\Spam\Eggs\" alt="other attribute cruft" />
<file alt="other attribute cruft" path="C:\Spam\Eggs\" />
<file path="C:\Spam\Spam\"></file>
```

And you may even see these, legal or not:

```
<file path='C:\Eggs\"Spam Spam Spam"\"Spammity Spam"'/>
```

You don't want to try to handle all of those possibilities in plain text. But if you don't handle all of them—and more besides—Murphy's Law guarantees that you're eventually going to run into a file that has whichever one you don't handle.

There are lots of different XML parsers, even built into the standard library, but I think the simplest is [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). So:

```
import os
import os.path
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

filepaths = {}
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    try:
        doc = ET.parse(os.path.join(directory, filename))
        paths = doc.find('paths')
        filepaths[filename] = [f.attrib['path'] for f in paths.findall('file')]
    except Exception as e:
        # You may want to log something, treat different exceptions differently, etc.
        pass
```

It should be pretty easy to figure out how to change this to handle all `paths` nodes instead of the first, or the first `file` node under `paths` instead of all of them, or the first `file` node that has a `path` attribute, etc.

If you're using Python 2.x, and the files are very big, this may be kind of slow. But you can fix that by explicitly using `cElementTree`. It's pretty common to do this:

```
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

That will give you the fast "C" implementation if possible, the slow one otherwise, in CPython 2.5+ (including 3.x, where the two were merged together), PyPy, etc.

---

Meanwhile, from other comments, you asked for additional things that weren't in your original post:

> i just need to… make the backslash into /

That's easy. Just call `s.replace('\\', '/')` on each path `s`.

However, this is kind of an odd thing to do. Going the other way around is pretty common (it's even built into the standard library—`os.path.normpath` will leave slashes alone on POSIX, but convert them to backslashes on Windows), but going from native-Windows to POSIX is usually part of a larger operation, like building a URL… in which case you probably want to use a higher-level function.

> in the file it was  - the result i want is C:\folder\folder

Here, it sounds like you want to strip off any trailing backslash. Again, this is an odd thing to do, and you probably actually want to do something higher-level than this (like `os.path.dirname` maybe?), but easy: `s.rstrip('\\')`.

Of course these last two contradict each other—if the result you want is `C:\folder\folder`, and you convert backslashes to forward slashes, you're not going to get the result you want.

But hopefully I've given you enough to build whatever it is you actually want.

Comment: I don't know what im doing wrong, my file look like this - <paths> and under it <file path="C:\folder\folder\"/> and many more paths in the same format, after it ends with </path> in the top of the file and in the bottom there are many more stuff. i run the code you wrote and what i get in filepaths is empty {} and in paths i get none.